# Of polynomial p(x) with degree n, show that: (a) $x_1x_2\ldots x_n=(-1)^n\frac{a_0}{a_n}$; (b) $x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_n=-\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_n}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $P(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\ldots+a_1x+a_0$ be a polynomial of degree $n\geq 1$. If $p(x)$ has $n$ zeros $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$, and is therefore expressible in the form.
$$p(x)=a_n(x-x_1)(x-x_2)\ldots(x-x_{n-1})(x-x_n)$$

show that:

(a) $x_1x_2\ldots x_n=(-1)^n\frac{a_0}{a_n}$;

(b) $x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_n=-\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_n}$.

Comment: Can you do the case $n=2$?

Comment: Thank you for answering, I start from $n=2$, and solved it!

Comment: Solved the whole problem? or solved the case $n=2$? If the whole problem, you could write it up & post it as an answer to the question.

Comment: Could you help me check my answer is right or wrong, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

denote polynomial of degree n as $p_n(x)$

$$
\begin{align}
p_1(x)&=a_1(x-x_1)\\
&=a_1x-a_1x_1\\
&=a_1x+a_0\\\\
p_2(x)&=a_2(x-x_1)(x-x_2)\\
&=a_2x^2-a_2xx_1-a_2xx_2+x_1x_2\\
&=a_2(x^2-(x_1+x_2)x+x_1x_2)\\
&=a_2x^2-a_2(x_1+x_2)x+x_1x_2\\
&=a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0\\\\
p_3(x)&=a_3(x-x_1)(x-x_2)(x-x_3)\\
&\ldots\\
&=a_3x^3-a_3(x_1+x_2+x_3)x^2+a_3(x_1x_2+x_1x_3+x_2x_3)x-a_3x_1x_2x_3\\
&=a_3x^3+a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0\\\\
p_n(x)&=a_n\prod_{i=1}^{n}(x-x_i)\\
&=a_n(x^n-(x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_n)x^{n-1}+(x_1x_2+x_1x_3+x_2x_3)x^{n-2}-\ldots-(\sum_{k_j\neq k_q}^{i=k}x_{k_1}x_{k_2}\ldots x_{k_i})x^{n-k}+\ldots+x_1x_2\ldots x_n),\quad(k\ is\ odd)\\
&=a_n(x^n-(x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_n)x^{n-1}+(x_1x_2+x_1x_3+x_2x_3)x^{n-2}-\ldots+x_1x_2\ldots x_n),\quad(n\ is\ even)\\
&=a_n(x^n-(x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_n)x^{n-1}+(x_1x_2+x_1x_3+x_2x_3)x^{n-2}-\ldots-x_1x_2\ldots x_n),\quad(n\ is\ odd)\\
&=a_n(x^n-(x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_n)x^{n-1}+(x_1x_2+x_1x_3+x_2x_3)x^{n-2}-\ldots+(-1)^nx_1x_2\ldots x_n)\\
&=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+a_1x+a_0
\end{align}
$$

then,
$$
\begin{align}
(-1)^na_nx_1x_2\ldots x_n&=a_0\\
x_1x_2\ldots x_n&=(-1)^n\frac{a_0}{a_n}
\\\\
-a_n(x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_n)x^{n-1}&=a_{n-1}x^{n-1}\\
x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_n&=-\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_n}\\
\end{align}
$$

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Don't worry about the "Community Bot". You've got the idea. Technically, to go from $n=3$ to general $n$, you should arrange this as a proof by induction.